# Is the economic output of the British crown dependencies included in Britain's national income?

Tags: macroeconomics, national-income

Is the economic output of the British crown dependencies included in Britain's Domestic Income ?
I know  from this Wikipedia article **https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crown_Dependencies**
,That crown dependency can pass their own laws and hence, as far as my understanding is concerned, control the movement of goods.
However, these crown dependencies also aren't soverign nations.

So does this mean that

a) We don't count the output of these crown dependencies in Britain's domestic income
and

b) If so, does this mean that when we calculate the world's income we don't include the income of these countries?

Thanks a lot for the help in advance!

Comment: Just to be clear, by crown dependencies , I mean places like the Isle of man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The UK economic territory excludes Crown dependencies (Channel Islands and the Isle of Man) [(see here, page 12, bottom section)](https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/863381/crown-dependencies-factsheet-february-2020.pdf)

So,

- the crown dependencies' income is not counted in the UK's domestic income and
- their income needs to be accounted for separately when calculating the world's income.

Note that for practical purposes the crown dependencies' contribution to the world aggregate will be negligible.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification !